# How do I get all environment variables as an array in PHP?

Tags: php, environment-variables

Title says it. I want to use this with [proc_open](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php), to append some variables to the current environment.

```
$current_env = get_all_env_vars_magically();
$env = array_merge($current_env, $new_vars);
$ph = proc_open($command, array(1 => array('pipe', 'w')), 
    $pipes, dirname(__FILE__), $env);
```

Edit: `$_ENV` is empty/not populated by default. `$_SERVER` contains so much more than env vars.

Comment: @Jack `$_ENV` is empty for me.

Comment: Then check your [variables_order](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order)

Comment: @Jack Thanks. But is there really nothing more portable?

Comment: what if get same by cli commang  `printenv` ?

Answer (score 12):

Since PHP7.1 the varname can now be omitted to retrieve an associative array of all environment variables.

try `getenv()` https://3v4l.org/fkFoR

PHP Docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php

Answer (score 4):

Try `getenv()` it gets the value of an environment variable.

The `$_ENV` array is created only if the value of the `variables_order` configuration directive contains `E`. If `$_ENV` isn't available, use `getenv( )` to retrieve an environment variable:

`$path = getenv('PATH')`;

Comment: Could you please add an example of `getenv()` usage?

Comment: where is `variables_order` configuration directive

Comment: So you can get value if you know variable name. Like getenv("PATH")... But how to get list of all names of variables?

Comment: You can find `variables_order` in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP 7.0, so `getenv()` is not available, and you are worried that `$_ENV` and `$_SERVER` don't contain all relevant variables, then, depending on your server security settings, you may be able to run `shell_exec('printenv')` to get all environment variables.

Answer (score -8):

Think you got to use $_ENV argument

Comment: Is there really nothing more portable?